# Will adding Eth. Switch and Arduino server to my home network work as expected? (DynDNS, SSH)

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, switch, dynamic-dns

I would like to buy an ethernet switch and put it into my network in order to be able to connect more devices to the web. The thing is, right now there is only one output from the router provided by my ISP and it goes directly to my PC. So using the DynDNS service from afraid.org I am able to access the PC through SSH.

My question is, will it work exactly the same even when I put a switch in between the router and the PC?

Also, I have one more concern. The reason for putting the switch in is that I want to use an Arduino server to send the updated dynamic IPs to the DynDNS service and also I want to use it to switch the PC on remotely. So the Arduino would be listening on a single port and occasionally it would send some packets out.

My reasoning for this working well is that 99.999% of the traffic will be initiated from the PC so the switch should be able to route the response packets (e.g. from a website) directly to the PC without flooding the Arduino as well. And when the traffic would be coming in (SSH to PC or special commands for the Arduino server) the switch should send the data to both PC and Arduino and one of them would handle it accordingly. This wouldn't be inefficient because the traffic initiated from outside would be negligible.

Now, is my reasoning correct or am I deluded about how switching works? Is it ok to have 2 devices under a single IP while each of them minds only specific ports and while the switch handles the correct distribution of packets?

Comment: Yep you got it correct. Add the switch.  As long as what the ISP providered is a router and not a simple modem you'll be fine.   If the ISP is only providing a modem then you don't want a switch, you want a 4 port router.

Comment: What's the model # of the router?

Comment: Ouch, I think you've got me, I thought it is a router but it is actually just a modem (Cisco EPC3208 http://bit.ly/2iIZh87). So if I used a switch and my ISP would provide me with only a single IP, only one device would work, right? But on the other hand, if they give me more IPs, then the Arduino will not have access to the IP of the PC and the DynDNS won't make much sense then. And if I buy a router, then the Arduino won't have access to the public IP either, or will it? I wish there were some cheap simple L3 switches...

Comment: With a router all devices get an internal or private IP.   For ports that need to be accessed from outside you port forward.  For Example: port 80 to the PC, Port 22 and port 8080 perhaps to the Ardunio, etc.  This is not rocket science or new technology, anyone with a single IP broadband connection and the need for inbound connections uses this method.  With the exception of port 80 for http, I typically even use port forward to remap ports. i.e public IP port 42022 finds my rPi at Private IP port 22.